# how to create and download pdf file using cezpdf in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function index() 
    {   
        $this->hello_world();
    }


    function hello_world()
    {
        $sol='<u>select</u>';

        $this->cezpdf->ezText('Hello World', 12, array('justification' => 'center'));
        $this->cezpdf->ezSetDy(-10);
        $content = '<table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr></table>';

        $this->cezpdf->ezText($content, 10);
        $data = $this->cezpdf->ezStream();

    }
```

i have using this code. its working fine was create pdf in new browser tab... but i need to download that file.can u help?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument to the `ezStream` function

`$this->cezpdf->ezStream(array('download'=>1));`

Comment: hi abdulla. thanks for reply... i try this.. still same problem.

Comment: did you include library ??

Comment: <?php

class Tutorial extends controller
{

 function Tutorial()
 {
  parent::Controller();
  $this->load->helper('download');  
  $this->load->library('cezpdf');
 }
 
 
 function index() 
 { 
  $this->hello_world();
 }


 function hello_world()
 {
  $sol='<u>select</u>';
  
  $this->cezpdf->ezText('Hello World', 12, array('justification' => 'center'));
  $this->cezpdf->ezSetDy(-10);
  $content = '<table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr></table>';

  $this->cezpdf->ezText($content, 10);
  $this->cezpdf->ezStream(array('download'=>1));
  
 }}

Comment: `$this->load->library('cezpdf');` exist ??

Comment: did you add `class.ezpdf.php` to library folder?? and rename it to  `cezpdf.php`

Comment: Check this [Generating PDF files using CodeIgniter](http://christophermonnat.com/blog/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter)

Comment: yes .. I'm already using this link. this code is working for pdf showing in browser. but i need to download that generating file.

Comment: It means your browser not support to download, Some browser it will automatically download.

Comment: hey did you remove `$data` in this?? `$data = $this->cezpdf->ezStream();`

Comment: yes remove it. and i want to download it desktop or some else. i am using browsers for chrome and firefox. both are updated.

Comment: in my bower also updated and its only show the pdf. not downloading

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>downloads/my.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to download</a>` but this also shows pdf

Comment: How can i load it into view file ?